# XMLStarlet does not select anything

Tags: command-line-interface, pom.xml, xmlstarlet

I have a typical pom.xml, and want to print the groupId, artifactId and version, separated by colon. I think that [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is the right tool for that. I tried several ways, but I always get an empty line.

```
xml sel -t -m project -v groupId -o : -v artifactId -o : -v version pom.xml
```

Expected output:

```
org.something.apps:app-acct:5.4
```

Real output: empty line

Even if I try to print just the groupId I get nothing:

```
xml sel -t -v project/groupId pom.xml
```

I am sure that the tool sees the elements because I can list them without problem:

```
xml el pom.xml
```

prints the following (correctly):

```
project
project/modelVersion
project/parent
project/parent/groupId
project/parent/artifactId
project/parent/version
project/groupId
project/artifactId
project/version
project/packaging
```

What's wrong?

Here is the cut-down version of pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.something</groupId>
        <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.something.apps</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-acct</artifactId>
    <version>5.4</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

</project>
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**UPDATE:** since version 1.5 the default namespace prefix '_' is available so the solution is reduced to this:

> xml sel -t -m _:project -v _:groupId -o : -v _:artifactId -o : -v _:version pom.xml

Thanks @JamieNelson for the heads-up.

---

Unfortunately, XMLStarlet is very picky about the default namespace. If the document has it declared (`xmlns=`), you have to declare it for XMLStarlet too, and prefix the elements with the name you have chosen (see [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html)):

> xml sel -N my=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -m my:project -v my:groupId -o : -v my:artifactId -o : -v my:version pom.xml

Running the above command gives the expected output:

```
org.something.apps:app-acct:5.4
```

However, if the document does NOT have the default namespace declared (or the namespace has a slightly different URL), the above command will NOT work, which is a real PITA. A more universal solution is to remove the default namespace declaration before selecting the elements. As of XMLStarlet 1.3.1, converting the XML to PYX format and back removes the namespace declarations:

> xml pyx pom.xml | xml p2x | xml sel -t -m project -v groupId -o : -v artifactId -o : -v version 2>nul

**UPDATE (2014-02-12):** as of XMLStarlet 1.4.2 the PYX <-> XML conversion is fixed (does not remove namespace declarations), so the above command will NOT work (thanks for Peter Gluck for the tip). Use the following command instead:

> xml pyx pom.xml | grep -v ^A | xml p2x | xml sel -t -m project -v groupId -o : -v artifactId -o : -v version

Note: the grep above removes ALL attributes from the document, not just namespace declarations. For this specific case (selecting element values from pom.xml where elements with non-default namespaces are not expected) it is Ok, but for a general XML you would remove just the default namespace declaration(s) and nothing else:

> xml pyx pom.xml | grep -v "^Axmlns " | xml p2x | xml sel -t -m project -v groupId -o : -v artifactId -o : -v version

---

Note (obsolete): the error redirection (`2>nul`) is necessary to hide the complaint about the (now) unknown namespace xsi:

> -:1.28: Namespace prefix xsi for schemaLocation on project is not defined

Another way of getting rid of the complaint is to remove the schemaLocation attribute (actually, this command removes all attributes from the PYX document, not just xsi:schemaLocation):

> xml pyx pom.xml | grep -v ^A | xml p2x | xml sel -t -m project -v groupId -o : -v artifactId -o : -v version

Comment: Your comment about prefixing elements with the (alias for?) the declared namespace is the crucial difference to the linked docs.

Comment: You helped me a lot! THX!

Answer (score 11):

The XML-> PYX -> XML trick did not work for me (using XMLStarlet version 1.4.2).  However, the [XMLStarlet documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html) contains this handy `sed` command that removes namespace declarations from an XML document:

```
sed -e 's/ xmlns.*=".*"//g'
```

That worked.  For the original question, the syntax would be:

```
cat pom.xml | sed -e 's/ xmlns.*=".*"//g' | xml sel -t -m project -v groupId -o : -v artifactId -o : -v version
```

Comment: Thanks for the update about the change in PYX -> XML conversion. This means that the last command line (with grep -v ^A) is now the preferred one. However, sed/grep/awk etc. should NOT be used on general XML: it works for that specific simple example in the documentation (and for my simplified example too), but it could easily create an invalid XML document. Example: running that "handy" sed on this: <D class="delta xmlns">a="X"; return a;</D> will result in this: <D class="delta; return a;</D>. On the other hand, running sed/grep/awk on PYX is OK, because that format is line-oriented.

Answer (score 4):

Since version 1.2 of xmlstarlet, you can just do this:

```
xml sel -t -m "//_:project" -v _:groupId -o : -v _:artifactId -o : -v _:version pom.xml
```

With a few other options here too:
http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html

Comment: in 1.3.1: does not work /
in 1.4.0: does not work /
in 1.6.1: WORKS