# Add XML node based on two of parents child values in the shell

Tags: xml, sh, xmlstarlet

How can I change this:

```
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

to that:

```
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/.../src/main/.../some.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

based on the value of "/dependencies/dependency/groupId" AND "/dependencies/dependency/artifactId"

in bash (by xmlstarlet,...)?

**Update**

Obviously this seems to be not clear enough.
So: The code has to find the dependency with groupId==xyz and artifactId==abc and then (and only then) add the two now nodes to the parent of the groupId and artifactId node.

Comment: Where are you getting the project.basedir variable from?

Comment: maven - but this is not the question (updating it)

Comment: When you says depending on "dependencies/dependency/groupId" AND "/dependencies/dependency/artifactId", what is the logic? Does it use the values in these fields? Does it update only if there are certain values?

Comment: added further explenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Jack Fleeting and the post from @uk4sx ([XMLStarlet does not select anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025492/xmlstarlet-does-not-select-anything)) - the namespace had to be set - I finally got it running like this (it it run from within a Dockerfile):

```
RUN xmlstarlet ed -L -N my=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 \
    --subnode "//my:dependencies/my:dependency[my:artifactId[./text()='abc']][my:groupId[./text()='xyz']]" \
      --type elem -n scope      -v "system" \
    --subnode "//my:dependencies/my:dependency[my:artifactId[./text()='abc']][my:groupId[./text()='xyz']]" \
      --type elem -n systemPath -v "\.../src/main/.../some.jar" \
    ./pom.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
--subnode "//dependency[//artifactId[./text()='abc']][//groupId[./text()='xyz']]" --type elem -n scope -v "system" \
--subnode "//dependency[//artifactId[./text()='abc']][//groupId[./text()='xyz']]" --type elem -n systemPath -v "some.jar" \
file.xml
```

Comment: @eventhorizon What's missing?

Comment: See my answer. Your suggestion is absolutely right. The important thing missing - sideshow but important - is the namespace “thing“... Others may have the same problem not knowing enough about it...