# Update version in pom.xml file using sed command

Tags: unix, sed

sample input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>currency-exchange-service</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <name>currency-exchange-service-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>currency-exchange-service</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <name>currency-exchange-service-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have calclated the 3.0.4 and using var2 variable to store it.
I was using this command to update

```
sed -i "s/<version>.*<\/version>/<version>$var2<\/version>/" pom.xml
```

but it was changing versions under each version tag.
But i need to change value under version tag which has project as a parent tag.

I tried with

```
sed -i "s/<project><version>.*<\/version>/<project><version>$var2<\/version>/" pom.xml
```

but its not working.

my script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
var1=$(echo '${project.version}' | mvn help:evaluate | grep -v '^[[]')
var2=$(echo "$var1" | awk -F. -v OFS=. '++$NF')
sed -i "s/<version>.*<\/version>/<version>$var2<\/version>/" pom.xml
echo "$var2"
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output is missing.

Comment: sed is in format "s/some to change/replace with/", you have way to many /

Comment: @Jotne I don't know much about sed. I am writing script for CI purpose. In which i need to update version of pom.xml . Any idea what i need to change in the above sed command to make it work.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated my question as u have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ xmlstarlet edit --update '//project/version' --value '3.0.4' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
  <version>3.0.4</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: xml edit --update '//project/version' --value '3.0.4' pom.xml       .This command does not update anything. I am using windows . I have updated my post with the xml that i have been working on.

Comment: If you're using Windows then why did you tag your question with `unix` and post a question about a shell script?

Comment: It is not about Windows vs Unix. If an XML element has the `xmlns` property set then the name of the element should be prefixed by the namespace when used, in the case of provided pom.xml file, the `xmlns` property is set but the namespace is not specified, which would make xmlstarlet fallback to the default namespace which is `_`, so the correct command becomes `xmlstarlet edit --update '//_:project/_:version' --value '3.0.4' file.xml`

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030791/9041064

Comment: @HoussemNasri the OP tagged their question "Unix" then said in a comment "I am using windows" so yes, [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790053/update-version-in-pom-xml-file-using-sed-command/68793198?noredirect=1#comment121594438_68793198) **is** about Windows vs Unix - specifically I asked why the OP tagged their question with Unix instead of Windows.

Comment: @HoussemNasri if you have an answer then post it as an answer, don't post it as a comment where others in future with a similar question may miss it and it can't be up/downvoted or easily commented on.

Answer (score 0):

This sed should do:

```
sed "/<version>/s/>.*</>${var2}</" pom.xml
<project>
       <version>3.0.4</version>
</project>
```

It searches for line with `<version>` then replace data between >xxx< with the variable.

Using regex, you can make sure what to find does not grab to much.

```
sed -E "/<version>/s/>[^<]+</>${var2}</" pom.xml
```

If you need to make sure it does not change other `version` than the one after `project` you can use `awk`

```
awk -v var=$var2 '/<project>/ {f=1} f && /<version>/ {sub(/>[^<]+</,">"var"<")} 1' pom.xml
<project>
       <version>3.0.4</version>
</project>
```

Sed version that test for `project` and change on next line

```
sed -E '/<project>/!b;n;s/<version>[^<]+</<version>'$var2'</' pom.xml
<project>
       <version>3.0.4</version>
</project>
```

Comment: when i tired this it is not giving me the expected result.  It is not updating anythig.

Comment: @KaramveerGahlot Does any of the other work?  What system are you on?

Comment: MY script.sh

#!/bin/bash
var1=$(echo '${project.version}' | mvn help:evaluate | grep -v '^[[]')
var2=$(echo $var1 | awk -F. -v OFS=. '++$NF')
awk -v var=$var2 '/<project>/ {f=1} f && /<version>/ {sub(/>[^<]+</,">"var"<")} 1' pom.xml
echo $var2

I used both the awk and sed commands but they are not updating anything. Any suggestion if i am doing something wrong ?
I am using windows.

Comment: Edit your post and add this information and script to it.  Not easy to see formatting in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlstarlet  edit -P --inplace --update '/_:project/_:version' --value '3.0.4' pom.xml
```

The reason behind the `_:` prefix is that each XML element with the xmlns property set, when referenced, should be prefixed by `<namespace>:`, in the case of the provided `pom.xml` file, the xmlns property is set but the namespace is not specified, which would make xmlstarlet fallback to the default namespace which is `_`.